# select every following segment until next sibling occurs and group them under target structure

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have input structure like below: 
After Item we have delivery_Info segment it can one per item or multiple for item, And the again Item followed by Delivery_Info. So we have group first item with following Delivery_Info and then next Item with their following Delivery_Info. Input and output structure is provided for more understanding.

`DataSet` cardinality is 1..n 
`EDI_Header` cardinality is 1..n 
`Item` cardinality is 1..n 
`Deliveryinfoset` cardinality 1..1 
`Delivery_info` cardinality 0..n

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ns:MM_FlatFile_CBOX_ORDRSP_Out xmlns:ns="urn:test:corp:pi:a:ecc:cbox:ordrsp:100">
        <DataSet>
            <EDI_Header>
                <LineIdent>SIM</LineIdent>
                <EDIPartnerNo>047866091</EDIPartnerNo>
                <MessageType>ORDRSP01</MessageType>
                <VersionNo>3A7V0</VersionNo>
                <Mode>102</Mode>
            </EDI_Header>
            <Header>
                <LineIdent>HO01</LineIdent>
                <SupplierOrderNo>6174625</SupplierOrderNo>
                <CustomerOrderNo>0038283143</CustomerOrderNo>
                <MessageFunction/>
                <Reference1>6174625</Reference1>
                <Reference2/>
                <Reference3/>
                <SoldToID>126919</SoldToID>
                <Partner2>126919</Partner2>
                <Partner3/>
                <ShipToID>126919</ShipToID>
                <ShipToName>XXXXX</ShipToName>
                <ShipToAddress/>
                <ShipToAddress2>XXXXX</ShipToAddress2>
                <ShipToCity>XXXXX</ShipToCity>
                <ShipToZIP>XXXXX</ShipToZIP>
                <ShipToCountry>FI</ShipToCountry>
                <CustContact>XXXXX</CustContact>
                <CustContactTelNo>XXXXX</CustContactTelNo>
                <TransportType>EUR</TransportType>
            </Header>
            <Item>
                <LineIdent>PO01</LineIdent>
                <SupplierOrderNo>6174625</SupplierOrderNo>
                <LineItemNo>D1L1</LineItemNo>
                <ActionCode>6</ActionCode>
                <ItemNoCust>P380200</ItemNoCust>
                <ItemNoSup>B39172B5364U410W 3</ItemNoSup>
                <Quantity>D1L1</Quantity>
                <Unit>PCE</Unit>
                <Price>0.4000</Price>
                <PriceType/>
                <QuantityPriceUnit>1</QuantityPriceUnit>
                <LineItemNoCust/>
            </Item>
            <Delivery_Info>
                <LineIdent>TE01</LineIdent>
                <SupplierOrderNo>6174625</SupplierOrderNo>
                <LineItemNo>D1L1DI1</LineItemNo>
                <Quantity>3000</Quantity>
                <Unit>PCE</Unit>
                <DelDateReq>20181130</DelDateReq>
                <DelDate>20181212</DelDate>
                <DateCode>C</DateCode>
                <QuantityOrdered>3000</QuantityOrdered>
                <DateCurrent>20181121</DateCurrent>
                <SysVar/>
            </Delivery_Info>
            <Item>
                <LineIdent>PO01</LineIdent>
                <SupplierOrderNo>6174625</SupplierOrderNo>
                <LineItemNo>D1L1</LineItemNo>
                <ActionCode>6</ActionCode>
                <ItemNoCust>P380200</ItemNoCust>
                <ItemNoSup>B39172B5364U410W 3</ItemNoSup>
                <Quantity>D1L1</Quantity>
                <Unit>PCE</Unit>
                <Price>0.4000</Price>
                <PriceType/>
                <QuantityPriceUnit>1</QuantityPriceUnit>
                <LineItemNoCust/>
            </Item>
            <Delivery_Info>
                <LineIdent>TE01</LineIdent>
                <SupplierOrderNo>6174625</SupplierOrderNo>
                <LineItemNo>D1L1DI1</LineItemNo>
                <Quantity>3000</Quantity>
                <Unit>PCE</Unit>
                <DelDateReq>20181130</DelDateReq>
                <DelDate>20181212</DelDate>
                <DateCode>C</DateCode>
                <QuantityOrdered>3000</QuantityOrdered>
                <DateCurrent>20181121</DateCurrent>
                <SysVar/>
            </Delivery_Info>
        </DataSet>
        <DataSet>
            <EDI_Header>
                <LineIdent>SIM</LineIdent>
                <EDIPartnerNo>047866091</EDIPartnerNo>
                <MessageType>ORDRSP01</MessageType>
                <VersionNo>3A7V0</VersionNo>
                <Mode>102</Mode>
            </EDI_Header>
            <Header>
                <LineIdent>HO01</LineIdent>
                <SupplierOrderNo>6174625</SupplierOrderNo>
                <CustomerOrderNo>0038283143</CustomerOrderNo>
                <MessageFunction/>
                <Reference1>6174625</Reference1>
                <Reference2/>
                <Reference3/>
                <SoldToID>126919</SoldToID>
                <Partner2>126919</Partner2>
                <Partner3/>
                <ShipToID>126919</ShipToID>
                <ShipToName>XXXXX</ShipToName>
                <ShipToAddress/>
                <ShipToAddress2>XXXXX</ShipToAddress2>
                <ShipToCity>XXXXX</ShipToCity>
                <ShipToZIP>XXXXX</ShipToZIP>
                <ShipToCountry>FI</ShipToCountry>
                <CustContact>XXXXX</CustContact>
                <CustContactTelNo>XXXXX</CustContactTelNo>
                <TransportType>EUR</TransportType>
            </Header>
            <Item>
                <LineIdent>PO01</LineIdent>
                <SupplierOrderNo>6174625</SupplierOrderNo>
                <LineItemNo>D1L1</LineItemNo>
                <ActionCode>6</ActionCode>
                <ItemNoCust>P380200</ItemNoCust>
                <ItemNoSup>B39172B5364U410W 3</ItemNoSup>
                <Quantity>D1L1</Quantity>
                <Unit>PCE</Unit>
                <Price>0.4000</Price>
                <PriceType/>
                <QuantityPriceUnit>1</QuantityPriceUnit>
                <LineItemNoCust/>
            </Item>
            <Delivery_Info>
                <LineIdent>TE01</LineIdent>
                <SupplierOrderNo>6174625</SupplierOrderNo>
                <LineItemNo>D1L1DI1</LineItemNo>
                <Quantity>3000</Quantity>
                <Unit>PCE</Unit>
                <DelDateReq>20181130</DelDateReq>
                <DelDate>20181212</DelDate>
                <DateCode>C</DateCode>
                <QuantityOrdered>3000</QuantityOrdered>
                <DateCurrent>20181121</DateCurrent>
                <SysVar/>
            </Delivery_Info>
            <Delivery_Info>
                <LineIdent>TE01</LineIdent>
                <SupplierOrderNo>6174625</SupplierOrderNo>
                <LineItemNo>D1L1DI1</LineItemNo>
                <Quantity>3000</Quantity>
                <Unit>PCE</Unit>
                <DelDateReq>20181130</DelDateReq>
                <DelDate>20181212</DelDate>
                <DateCode>C</DateCode>
                <QuantityOrdered>3000</QuantityOrdered>
                <DateCurrent>20181121</DateCurrent>
                <SysVar/>
            </Delivery_Info>
            <Delivery_Info>
                <LineIdent>TE01</LineIdent>
                <SupplierOrderNo>6174625</SupplierOrderNo>
                <LineItemNo>D1L1DI1</LineItemNo>
                <Quantity>3000</Quantity>
                <Unit>PCE</Unit>
                <DelDateReq>20181130</DelDateReq>
                <DelDate>20181212</DelDate>
                <DateCode>C</DateCode>
                <QuantityOrdered>3000</QuantityOrdered>
                <DateCurrent>20181121</DateCurrent>
                <SysVar/>
            </Delivery_Info>
        </DataSet>
    </ns:MM_FlatFile_CBOX_ORDRSP_Out>
```

Target Structure should be-->

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ns:MM_FlatFile_CBOX_ORDRSP_Out 

xmlns:ns="urn:test:corp:pi:a:ecc:cbox:ordrsp:100">
    <DataSet>
        <EDI_Header>
            <LineIdent>SIM</LineIdent>
            <EDIPartnerNo>047866091</EDIPartnerNo>
            <MessageType>ORDRSP01</MessageType>
            <VersionNo>3A7V0</VersionNo>
            <Mode>102</Mode>
        </EDI_Header>
        <Header>
            <LineIdent>HO01</LineIdent>
            <SupplierOrderNo>6174625</SupplierOrderNo>
            <CustomerOrderNo>0038283143</CustomerOrderNo>
            <MessageFunction/>
            <Reference1>6174625</Reference1>
            <Reference2/>
            <Reference3/>
            <SoldToID>126919</SoldToID>
            <Partner2>126919</Partner2>
            <Partner3/>
            <ShipToID>126919</ShipToID>
            <ShipToName>XXXXX</ShipToName>
            <ShipToAddress/>
            <ShipToAddress2>XXXXX</ShipToAddress2>
            <ShipToCity>XXXXX</ShipToCity>
            <ShipToZIP>XXXXX</ShipToZIP>
            <ShipToCountry>FI</ShipToCountry>
            <CustContact>XXXXX</CustContact>
            <CustContactTelNo>XXXXX</CustContactTelNo>
            <TransportType>EUR</TransportType>
        </Header>
        <Item>
            <LineIdent>PO01</LineIdent>
            <SupplierOrderNo>6174625</SupplierOrderNo>
            <LineItemNo>D1L1</LineItemNo>
            <ActionCode>6</ActionCode>
            <ItemNoCust>P380200</ItemNoCust>
            <ItemNoSup>B39172B5364U410W 3</ItemNoSup>
            <Quantity>D1L1</Quantity>
            <Unit>PCE</Unit>
            <Price>0.4000</Price>
            <PriceType/>
            <QuantityPriceUnit>1</QuantityPriceUnit>
            <LineItemNoCust/>
            <Deliveryinfoset>
                <Delivery_Info>
                    <LineIdent>TE01</LineIdent>
                    <SupplierOrderNo>6174625</SupplierOrderNo>
                    <LineItemNo>D1L1DI1</LineItemNo>
                    <Quantity>3000</Quantity>
                    <Unit>PCE</Unit>
                    <DelDateReq>20181130</DelDateReq>
                    <DelDate>20181212</DelDate>
                    <DateCode>C</DateCode>
                    <QuantityOrdered>3000</QuantityOrdered>
                    <DateCurrent>20181121</DateCurrent>
                    <SysVar/>
                </Delivery_Info>
            </Deliveryinfoset>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <LineIdent>PO01</LineIdent>
            <SupplierOrderNo>6174625</SupplierOrderNo>
            <LineItemNo>D1L1</LineItemNo>
            <ActionCode>6</ActionCode>
            <ItemNoCust>P380200</ItemNoCust>
            <ItemNoSup>B39172B5364U410W 3</ItemNoSup>
            <Quantity>D1L1</Quantity>
            <Unit>PCE</Unit>
            <Price>0.4000</Price>
            <PriceType/>
            <QuantityPriceUnit>1</QuantityPriceUnit>
            <LineItemNoCust/>
            <Deliveryinfoset>
                <Delivery_Info>
                    <LineIdent>TE01</LineIdent>
                    <SupplierOrderNo>6174625</SupplierOrderNo>
                    <LineItemNo>D1L1DI1</LineItemNo>
                    <Quantity>3000</Quantity>
                    <Unit>PCE</Unit>
                    <DelDateReq>20181130</DelDateReq>
                    <DelDate>20181212</DelDate>
                    <DateCode>C</DateCode>
                    <QuantityOrdered>3000</QuantityOrdered>
                    <DateCurrent>20181121</DateCurrent>
                    <SysVar/>
                </Delivery_Info>
            </Deliveryinfoset>
        </Item>
    </DataSet>
    <DataSet>
        <EDI_Header>
            <LineIdent>SIM</LineIdent>
            <EDIPartnerNo>047866091</EDIPartnerNo>
            <MessageType>ORDRSP01</MessageType>
            <VersionNo>3A7V0</VersionNo>
            <Mode>102</Mode>
        </EDI_Header>
        <Header>
            <LineIdent>HO01</LineIdent>
            <SupplierOrderNo>6174625</SupplierOrderNo>
            <CustomerOrderNo>0038283143</CustomerOrderNo>
            <MessageFunction/>
            <Reference1>6174625</Reference1>
            <Reference2/>
            <Reference3/>
            <SoldToID>126919</SoldToID>
            <Partner2>126919</Partner2>
            <Partner3/>
            <ShipToID>126919</ShipToID>
            <ShipToName>XXXXX</ShipToName>
            <ShipToAddress/>
            <ShipToAddress2>XXXXX</ShipToAddress2>
            <ShipToCity>XXXXX</ShipToCity>
            <ShipToZIP>XXXXX</ShipToZIP>
            <ShipToCountry>FI</ShipToCountry>
            <CustContact>XXXXX</CustContact>
            <CustContactTelNo>XXXXX</CustContactTelNo>
            <TransportType>EUR</TransportType>
        </Header>
        <Item>
            <LineIdent>PO01</LineIdent>
            <SupplierOrderNo>6174625</SupplierOrderNo>
            <LineItemNo>D1L1</LineItemNo>
            <ActionCode>6</ActionCode>
            <ItemNoCust>P380200</ItemNoCust>
            <ItemNoSup>B39172B5364U410W 3</ItemNoSup>
            <Quantity>D1L1</Quantity>
            <Unit>PCE</Unit>
            <Price>0.4000</Price>
            <PriceType/>
            <QuantityPriceUnit>1</QuantityPriceUnit>
            <LineItemNoCust/>
            <Deliveryinfoset>
                <Delivery_Info>
                    <LineIdent>TE01</LineIdent>
                    <SupplierOrderNo>6174625</SupplierOrderNo>
                    <LineItemNo>D1L1DI1</LineItemNo>
                    <Quantity>3000</Quantity>
                    <Unit>PCE</Unit>
                    <DelDateReq>20181130</DelDateReq>
                    <DelDate>20181212</DelDate>
                    <DateCode>C</DateCode>
                    <QuantityOrdered>3000</QuantityOrdered>
                    <DateCurrent>20181121</DateCurrent>
                    <SysVar/>
                </Delivery_Info>
                <Delivery_Info>
                    <LineIdent>TE01</LineIdent>
                    <SupplierOrderNo>6174625</SupplierOrderNo>
                    <LineItemNo>D1L1DI1</LineItemNo>
                    <Quantity>3000</Quantity>
                    <Unit>PCE</Unit>
                    <DelDateReq>20181130</DelDateReq>
                    <DelDate>20181212</DelDate>
                    <DateCode>C</DateCode>
                    <QuantityOrdered>3000</QuantityOrdered>
                    <DateCurrent>20181121</DateCurrent>
                    <SysVar/>
                </Delivery_Info>
                <Delivery_Info>
                    <LineIdent>TE01</LineIdent>
                    <SupplierOrderNo>6174625</SupplierOrderNo>
                    <LineItemNo>D1L1DI1</LineItemNo>
                    <Quantity>3000</Quantity>
                    <Unit>PCE</Unit>
                    <DelDateReq>20181130</DelDateReq>
                    <DelDate>20181212</DelDate>
                    <DateCode>C</DateCode>
                    <QuantityOrdered>3000</QuantityOrdered>
                    <DateCurrent>20181121</DateCurrent>
                    <SysVar/>
                </Delivery_Info>
            </Deliveryinfoset>
        </Item>
    </DataSet>
</ns:MM_FlatFile_CBOX_ORDRSP_Out>
```

My XSLT Code which is not working if we have more than one item with their delivery info

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:ns="urn:test:corp:pi:a:ecc:cbox:ordrsp:100" exclude-result-prefixes="ns">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<MM_FlatFile_CBOX_ORDRSP_Out>
    <xsl:for-each select="/ns:MM_FlatFile_CBOX_ORDRSP_Out/DataSet">

    <DataSet>
        <EDI_Header>

            <LineIdent>
                <xsl:value-of select="./EDI_Header/LineIdent"/>
            </LineIdent>

            <EDIPartnerNo>
                <xsl:value-of select="./EDI_Header/EDIPartnerNo"/>
            </EDIPartnerNo>

            <MessageType>
                <xsl:value-of select="'ORDRSP01'"/>
            </MessageType>

            <VersionNo>
                <xsl:value-of select="'3A7V0'"/>
            </VersionNo>

            <Mode>
                <xsl:value-of select="'102'"/>
            </Mode>
        </EDI_Header>

        <Header>
            <LineIdent>
                <xsl:value-of select="./Header/LineIdent"/>
            </LineIdent>

            <SupplierOrderNo>
                <xsl:value-of select="./Header/SupplierOrderNo"/>
            </SupplierOrderNo>

            <CustomerOrderNo>
                <xsl:value-of select="./Header/CustomerOrderNo"/>
            </CustomerOrderNo>

            <MessageFunction>
                <xsl:value-of select="./Header/MessageFunction"/>
            </MessageFunction>

            <Reference1>
                <xsl:value-of select="./Header/Reference1"/>
            </Reference1>

            <Reference2>
                <xsl:value-of select="./Header/Reference2"/>
            </Reference2>

            <Reference3>
                <xsl:value-of select="./Header/Reference3"/>
            </Reference3>

            <SoldToID>
                <xsl:value-of select="./Header/SoldToID"/>
            </SoldToID>
            <Partner2>
                <xsl:value-of select="./Header/Partner2"/>
            </Partner2>

            <Partner3>
                <xsl:value-of select="./Header/Partner3"/>
            </Partner3>

            <ShipToID>
                <xsl:value-of select="./Header/ShipToID"/>
            </ShipToID>

            <ShipToName>
                <xsl:value-of select="./Header/ShipToName"/>
            </ShipToName>

            <ShipToAddress>
                <xsl:value-of select="./Header/ShipToAddress"/>
            </ShipToAddress>

            <ShipToAddress2>
                <xsl:value-of select="./Header/ShipToAddress2"/>
            </ShipToAddress2>

            <ShipToCity>
                <xsl:value-of select="./Header/ShipToCity"/>
            </ShipToCity>

            <ShipToZIP>
                <xsl:value-of select="./Header/ShipToZIP"/>
            </ShipToZIP>

            <ShipToCountry>
                <xsl:value-of select="./Header/ShipToCountry"/>
            </ShipToCountry>

            <CustContact>
                <xsl:value-of select="./Header/CustContact"/>
            </CustContact>

            <CustContactTelNo>
                <xsl:value-of select="./Header/CustContactTelNo"/>
            </CustContactTelNo>

            <TransportType>
                <xsl:value-of select="./Header/TransportType"/>
            </TransportType>

        </Header>
        <xsl:for-each select="./Item">
        <Item>


            <LineIdent>
                <xsl:value-of select="./LineIdent"/>
            </LineIdent>

            <SupplierOrderNo>
                <xsl:value-of select="./SupplierOrderNo"/>
            </SupplierOrderNo>

            <LineItemNo>
                <xsl:value-of select="./LineItemNo"/>
            </LineItemNo>

            <ActionCode>
                <xsl:value-of select="./ActionCode"/>
            </ActionCode>

            <ItemNoCust>
                <xsl:value-of select="./ItemNoCust"/>
            </ItemNoCust>

            <ItemNoSup>
                <xsl:value-of select="./ItemNoSup"/>
            </ItemNoSup>

            <Quantity>
                <xsl:value-of select="./Quantity"/>
            </Quantity>

            <Unit>
                <xsl:value-of select="./Unit"/>
            </Unit>

            <Price>
                <xsl:value-of select="./Price"/>
            </Price>

            <PriceType>
                <xsl:value-of select="./PriceType"/>
            </PriceType>

            <QuantityPriceUnit>
                <xsl:value-of select="./QuantityPriceUnit"/>
            </QuantityPriceUnit>

            <LineItemNoCust>
                <xsl:value-of select="./LineItemNoCust"/>
            </LineItemNoCust>

            <xsl:for-each select="../Delivery_Info">

            <DeliveryInfoSet>
                <Delivery_Info>
                    <LineIdent>
                        <xsl:value-of select="./LineIdent"/>
                    </LineIdent>

                    <SupplierOrderNo>
                        <xsl:value-of select="./SupplierOrderNo"/>
                    </SupplierOrderNo>

                    <LineItemNo>
                        <xsl:value-of select="./LineItemNo"/>
                    </LineItemNo>

                    <Quantity>
                        <xsl:value-of select="./Quantity"/>
                    </Quantity>

                    <Unit>
                        <xsl:value-of select="./Unit"/>
                    </Unit>
                    <DelDateReq>
                        <xsl:value-of select="./DelDateReq"/>
                    </DelDateReq>

                    <DelDate>
                        <xsl:value-of select="./DelDate"/>
                    </DelDate>

                    <DateCode>
                        <xsl:value-of select="./DateCode"/>
                    </DateCode>

                    <QuantityOrdered>
                        <xsl:value-of select="./QuantityOrdered"/>
                    </QuantityOrdered>

                    <DateCurrent>
                        <xsl:value-of select="./DateCurrent"/>
                    </DateCurrent>

                    <SysVar>
                        <xsl:value-of select="./SysVar"/>
                    </SysVar>

                </Delivery_Info>
            </DeliveryInfoSet>

            </xsl:for-each>

        </Item>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </DataSet>
    </xsl:for-each>
</MM_FlatFile_CBOX_ORDRSP_Out>




</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks

May I request you people to help me in this requirement

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "Root cardinality is 1..n". An XML document can have only one root element. -- More importantly: where is the closing tag of `<Header>`?!

Comment: Hi Michael I am putting real input value here

Comment: Hi Michael: Now I have corrected the entire input structure and required target structure.

Answer (score 0):

Given a **well-formed (!)** input such as:

**XML**

```
<Root>
     <Header>
       <Header_No>XXX</Header_No>
     </Header>
     <Item>
        <Item_No>1</Item_No>
        <Price>XXX</Price>
     </Item>
     <Delivery_Info>
        <Delivery_no>101</Delivery_no>
        <Delivery_Date>XXXXX</Delivery_Date>
     </Delivery_Info>
     <Delivery_Info>
        <Delivery_no>102</Delivery_no>
        <Delivery_Date>XXXXX</Delivery_Date>
     </Delivery_Info>
     <Delivery_Info>
        <Delivery_no>103</Delivery_no>
        <Delivery_Date>XXXXX</Delivery_Date>
     </Delivery_Info>
     <Item>
        <Item_No>2</Item_No>
        <Price>XXX</Price>
     </Item>
     <Delivery_Info>
        <Delivery_no>201</Delivery_no>
        <Delivery_Date>XXXXX</Delivery_Date>
     </Delivery_Info> 
     <Delivery_Info>
        <Delivery_no>202</Delivery_no>
        <Delivery_Date>XXXXX</Delivery_Date>
     </Delivery_Info> 
</Root>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="delivery" match="Delivery_Info" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::Item[1])" />

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Header"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="Item">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
                <Deliveryinfoset>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="key('delivery', generate-id())"/>
                </Deliveryinfoset>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
  <Header>
    <Header_No>XXX</Header_No>
  </Header>
  <Item>
    <Item_No>1</Item_No>
    <Price>XXX</Price>
    <Deliveryinfoset>
      <Delivery_Info>
        <Delivery_no>101</Delivery_no>
        <Delivery_Date>XXXXX</Delivery_Date>
      </Delivery_Info>
      <Delivery_Info>
        <Delivery_no>102</Delivery_no>
        <Delivery_Date>XXXXX</Delivery_Date>
      </Delivery_Info>
      <Delivery_Info>
        <Delivery_no>103</Delivery_no>
        <Delivery_Date>XXXXX</Delivery_Date>
      </Delivery_Info>
    </Deliveryinfoset>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Item_No>2</Item_No>
    <Price>XXX</Price>
    <Deliveryinfoset>
      <Delivery_Info>
        <Delivery_no>201</Delivery_no>
        <Delivery_Date>XXXXX</Delivery_Date>
      </Delivery_Info>
      <Delivery_Info>
        <Delivery_no>202</Delivery_no>
        <Delivery_Date>XXXXX</Delivery_Date>
      </Delivery_Info>
    </Deliveryinfoset>
  </Item>
</Root>
```

Comment: Hi Michael, Thank you very much for quick help but my problem is Root itself is being repeated several times.

Comment: I think you should be able to apply this to your situation.